# ActionDispatch middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, middleware

Q: What does ActionDispatch do and where can I read documentation on it?

I've been searching for over an hour and can't find concrete answers about this other than a vague "It does stuff with requests, responses, etc." right here on stack overflow. I'm attempting to gain a deep understanding of all the default rails middleware like ActionDispatch::Static, requestID, etc. but there doesn't seem to be much info out there.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/
Click on ActionDispatch on the left. You can go as deep as looking at the source code of rails there. Hope that's what you're looking for.